# Jasmine testing object having optional properties

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a interface IData with optional properties.

```
interface IData {
 prop1: string,
 prop2?: string
}
setObj(){
  prop1 = 'abc';
  prop2 = 'xyz';
  let obj1 : IData = {
                       prop1: this.prop1,
                       prop2: this.prop2
                     }
}
```

while unitTesting expecting value of obj1 throws error

```
expect(obj1).toEqual({
                prop1: 'abc',
                prop2: 'xyz' })
```

Argument of type '{prop1: string; prop2: string;}'is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected

Comment: Hard to see what the problem is, you don't have enough of the code. Can you reproduce it at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ I don't get an error when I try something close to what you have

Comment: Can you tell us where are `this.prop1` and `this.prop2` defined? You defined local variables prop1/prop2 but used `this.prop1/2` instead

Comment: Also, what is the line that is causing the error? Is it the assignment into `obj1` ?

Answer (score 0):

check each individual properties instead of whole object

```
expect(obj1.prop1).toEqual('abc')
expect(obj1.prop2).toEqual('xyz')
```

Also can use `objectContaining` to compare the partial objects.

```
expect(obj1).objectContaining({
            prop1: 'abc',
            prop2: 'xyz' })
```

Comment: What if there are more properties? Doesn't scale, doesn't really answer the question, just offers a workaround, probably better off as a comment

Comment: `objectContaining` is still a workaround. The problem is typing, you shouldn't use a different solution if you don't understand the problem and if you are forced to, it should be clear that you are using a sub par solution